# Message Driven Bean annotation properties in a constants file

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I am working on an application that utilizes a Message Driven Bean for sending e-mails. One thing I wanted to do was move most of the application constants to a constants file to make maintaining the application easier.

I tried to move the propertyValues for things like the mappedName, acknowledgeMode, destinationType, etc to a constants file, and use a static import to reference them, but that seemed to cause an error when trying to compile the application:

```
JMS resource not created
```

When I went back and removed the constants and used hardcoded strings it worked. So, my question is, in dealing with EJB's(or maybe annotations in general), must these properties be hardcoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The propertyValues must be a [compile-time constant expresion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.28),
therefore, it can not be defined at runtime as you pretend. This limitation applies to all kinds of Java annotation
it is not a restriction imposed for EJBs.

Take in mind that an alternative provided by the EJB specification
is to use a [deployment descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951448/can-we-use-ejb-jar-xml-instead-of-annotations-for-messagedrivenbeanmdb-in-ejb) file instead of to annotate your code.

> 5.4.1Required MessageDrivenBean Metadata
>
> A message-driven bean must be annotated with the MessageDriven annotation
> or denoted in the deployment descriptor as a message-driven bean.